# Highlighting cells if duplicate NOT using conditional formatting

Tags: excel, duplicates, highlight

In one column, I have a name, and in another, a description.  I want to highlight any duplicate description that occur within the same name.  Once the name changes, I need to start the duplicate search again until the name changes again.

Conditional formatting will highlight duplicates in the description column, but pays no attention to the name column.

[image]

With conditional formatting, you can see that the bottom two are highlighted, but they are not duplicates within the same name.  The top "Information Request" should not be highlighted either.

Is there a way to highlight duplicates in groups of names?

EDIT: When attempting tigeravatar's answer, I get this output which is incorrect:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Delete your existing conditional format rule for duplicates
- Select cell G2
- Create a new Conditional Format rule with a formula
- Use this formula: `=COUNTIFS($D:$D,$D2,$G:$G,$G2)>1`
- Apply the conditional format rule to your column G range

Result:

[image]

Comment: That worked for the sample data, but when I used it in the full sheet it highlighted too many that are not duplicates within the names.  I'll try that again on my next break.

Comment: @12fretter Need better sample data then, hard to adjust without seeing what's going wrong.

Comment: @12fretter I got your reply from your attempt to edit the answer.  I have edited your question to show the results you got.  It looks like you may not have cell G2 selected when you entered the conditional format formula.

Comment: Ah...got it!  Thanks a bunch!  I wish I knew how you came up with that, but thanks!